# Suggestions for cross platform graphics technologies which support older browsers

Tags: website-design, graphics

I need to present a lot of information to my users pulled from a MySql.

I am looking for various options to display the data with cool graphics.

Are there any ways to make use of SVG, for instance, in various old browsers like IE5? I am mainly looking for the right web technology with cross platform support.

Thank you all for your suggestions!

Comment: Why do you need to support IE5? Is your target audience Windows 98/Me users? Even [Windows NT 4.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_4.0) users have access to IE6.

Answer (score 1):

[Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) allow you to target CSS directly at specific versions of internet explorer, or versions above a specific version. This helps fix bugs seen in only a single browser version, or target graphics at specific IE browsers and not others e.g. showing a gif to IE6 but a png to 7 or above.

In wider terms the general principal for website design vs old browsers is [graceful degradation](http://webdesign.about.com/od/webdesignglossary/g/graceful-degradation.htm) i.e. that users of very old browsers would get a usable site, just not the all singing all dancing experience that users of more recent browsers get.

To address your question directly [this plugin assists with SVG in version 6](http://www.savarese.com/software/svgplugin/) or above, [google also offer some libraries](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/), and this might provide a little more data about [SVG in IE5](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/xsl-list/2000-08/msg01103.html) specifically.